# When applying location of a translated object with mirror modifyer the global axes are used

Tags: axis, mirror-modifier

I really don't know how I archived this. Can anybody tell me how to get the mirror modifier to use local axes when applying the object's location?

[image: Applying location to a translated object with mirror mod]

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I have a tutorial video where a simple plane where cut into two half's. One has been deleted and subset with a modifier for demonstration purposes.
Then the plane is moved and the location has been applied.
On the video the mirrored part is still in position just as expected.
Every time I apply the location, the GLOBAL Axis are used for the mirror. I retried that with a simple new project but get the same result.
Q is what do I make wrong. Or is there a global Setting that I accidentally switched?

Comment: Do you have a link to this tutorial video?

Comment: It's a big german one, the part I used seems to be only buy able.
Here is a video of another part: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoc9_dRcvn4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the mirror modifier uses the object origin as pivot point, to mirror the mesh along global axes; when you apply the loc, the object origin goes to world origin (0,0,0).

You can create a new object (maybe an empty) and use it as new pivot point selecting its name in the mirror modifier "Mirror object" menu.

This empty can be moved and rotated along with the object, to get the mirroring performed on any desired local axes.

[image]